# Play sound with Oboe with .obb file

Tags: oboe

Hello sorry I'm begginer.
I don't have my sound files in my assets folder but in my .obb
I'm using the RythmGame sample who is using only assets folder.
I'm trying to use DataSound but only AAssetDataSource is used in my sample for create a DataSound.
I look at Asset and NDKExtractor for the decode function, but can only be use with an AAsset from an AssetManager...
How can I play sound from an .obb with Oboe ?
Can someone help me with that problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by [getting the path to your expansion file](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files#ReadingTheFile) and [passing that through JNI to your native code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/android-mk/native-media/jni/native-media-jni.c#L329), opening it as a normal file object and passing the contents to the extractor.

You're right about the `NDKExtractor::decode` methods - they take an `AAsset *`, however it should be pretty easy to update them to take the file descriptor from your open file instead.

Comment: Thanks, my last problem si about the setDataSourceFd, I try to use setDataSource with the location and I can play the sound. For other man who want to do the same. I just create all my sound file from my obb in filesDir at start of the app. At give the location of my all files to the extractor with the AMediaExtractor_setDataSource(extractor, location) function. All other code don't need to be modify from the sample NDKExtractor::decode function from RythmGame sample https://github.com/google/oboe/tree/master/samples/RhythmGame